# Can't access my MVC web application hosted on IIS 7.5 through Internet

Tags: networking, web-server, accessibility, iis-7.5, mvc

I'm hosting my MVC web application on IIS 7.5, and do the following:

1. Add *Application Pool* and change *Identity* to `NetworkService`;
2. Edit web application folder permissions to `everyone`;
3. Files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`;
4. Get myWANip.

This works fine when running locally. But when deployed, the web site isn't accessible (the browser reports "this webpage is not available").

What could be wrong?

Comment: Yes its work in debug mode and work in localhost,but its not accessible from other networks (this webpage not available)

Comment: Did you assigned any other ports other than the default port?

Comment: Can you access it form local computer (not via VS)

Comment: No i dont assigned i'll try to add a specific port

Comment: If you can't access it from local computer, why are you trying over a network?

Comment: @AhmedSalameh : Are you trying this from a remote computer in a LAN or outside to the LAN? Did you checked whether your firewall is open to that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, web page not available doesn't mean it can't be found, just that it isn't available. This may be a path issue, or not.

I will assume you've set up site in IIS correctly. If so, click on it, click on the browse tab at the bottom and view the homepage from within ISS. This will at least load the page it thinks it should be at.

Since there are so many reasons why it's not working, the first thing to do is navigate to the folder in question. Go to your Views folder and add an HTML file. Open the file in the browser. Now compare this path to that you're trying to use.

Make sure your web.config file allows debugging as this may help.

Is port 80 open? Ensure it is open in the Firewall.

Try opening the website direct from the wwwroot folder

Do you have  [MVC installed](http://www.asp.net/mvc) on the machine?